# Calculate the area made with the quarter arcs of circles without Integration

Tags: geometry, area

Is there any simple solution to find the area made with the quarter arcs of the circles **BLUE AREA** without using calculus(integrating!)?
[image]

Comment: Please refer to : https://www.quora.com/Four-quadrants-are-drawn-inside-a-square-with-each-side-14-cm-as-radius-What-is-the-area-of-the-section-common-in-all-the-four-quadrants

Comment: The blue area is that of the square through the corners plus four circle segments. These are found as the difference of a circular sector and a triangle.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Could you please post an answer if you've found one?

Comment: @FreeMind: sorry, I gave you the hint, the dirty work is yours.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity let the square side be equal to 10:
[image]